# Trigger event on host from directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to automatically close an [NG Bootstrap alert](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/examples) after a set period of time. The alert already has the close event which I'm using in the component. I'm adding the additional timeout functionality as a directive which should be able to trigger the close event itself. Something like this?

**close-on-timeout.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCloseOnTimeout]'
})
export class CloseOnTimeoutDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() appCloseOnTimeout: number;
  @HostBinding('close') close: CloseEvent;

  constructor () {}

  ngOnInit () {
    setTimeout (() => this.close(), this.appCloseOnTimeout);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use the directive like this:

```
<ngb-alert
  [dismissible]="alert.dismissible"
  [type]="alert.type"
  (close)="onClose(i)"
  [appCloseOnTimeout]="1000"
>
```

What's the best way to access the host element's close event? I've tried using an `ElementRef` instead but still can't find a way to access the events.

Comment: `@Input appCloseOnTimeout: number;` and settimeout on that passed value?

Comment: It's not the binding to the timeout value that's the porblem, it's the triggering the close event on the host that isn't working. I'll add the Input to the question so it's a bit more clear.

Comment: hmm, maybe `ngAfterViewInit` will help than?

Comment: What is the CloseEvent ?

Comment: The `close` event is part of the `ngb-alert`: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/api. I'm just trying to make a directive that can be placed on the ngb-alert and trigger the `ngb-alert`'s close. `CloseEvent` is quite possibly not the right type here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like...

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
 selector: '[appCloseOnTimeout]'
})
export class CloseOnTimeoutDirective implements OnInit {
 @Input() appCloseOnTimeout: number;
 @Output() close:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 constructor () {}

 ngOnInit () {
  setTimeout (() => this.closeWrapp(), this.appCloseOnTimeout);
 }

 closeWrapp(){
  this.close.emit()
 }
}
```

Comment: I get the TypeScript error `Generic type 'EventEmitter<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)` when I use the event emitter. I don't think this is going to help with calling a hosts event though.

Comment: oh my bad you can pass like `@Output('close') close:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();`

Comment: I still get `ERROR TypeError: _this.close is not a function`. I don't think this is accessing the event on the host component.

Comment: This actually does work if you use `this.close.emit()`. There's really no reason to add that `closeWrapp` function tho - just use `this.close.emit()` in the `=>` function.

Comment: Or as per @KirkLarkin says you can direct pass.

Comment: `.emit`... That's what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not `EventEmitter`?

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostBinding,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCloseOnTimeout]'
})
export class CloseOnTimeoutDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() appCloseOnTimeout: number;
  @Output() close: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.onClose(), this.appCloseOnTimeout);
  }
  
  onClose() {
    console.log('local close');
    this.close.emit();
  }
}
```